# How HashMap replaces the value of a key without calling equals method

Tags: java, hashmap, equals

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee e1=new Employee(1);
        Employee e2=new Employee(1);
        HashMap<Employee,String> map=new HashMap<Employee,String>();
        map.put(e1, "A");
        map.put(e1, "B");
        map.put(e2, "C");
        }
}
class Employee{
    private int id;
     Employee(int id){
         this.id=id;
     }

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    System.out.println("hascode is ="+this.id);
    return  this.id;
}
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    System.out.println("Equals");
        return super.equals(obj);
    }
}
```

When I put the same object e1 again, equals() method does not get called,then how the value B is replaced for the key e1 without being checked in the map's existing objects? (which I suppose is the job of equals method)

Comment: In your second put, `map.put(e1, "B")`, you are simply overwriting that key and its value with the new string.  Why would you expect that either `equals()` or `hashcode()` would be needed there?

Comment: AFAIK there is also nothing happening here with collisions, e.g. a different key coincidentally hitting the same bucket.  Your put is basically a kill order, i.e. just clobber whatever is already there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The contract of the `Object.equals` method requires the implementation to be *reflexive*:

> It is *reflexive*: for any non-null reference value x, `x.equals(x)`
>   should return `true`.

That means that the `HashMap` implementation is allowed to, and in fact does, always compare using `==` first and only invokes the `equals` method if that comparison wasn't `true`. So if you replace the value of a key `e1` using the exact same object `e1`, it only uses the `==` comparison and never invokes the `equals` method.

If you look in the `HashMap` implementation that puts a value for a key, you will find variations of this statement twice:

```
if (e.hash == hash &&
    ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
    break;
```

(once for the first key in the hash bucket, and then in a loop to iterate over any other keys in the hash bucket)

Comment: nice explanation , you just beat me :) +1.